# How do I change volume sizes on Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 without reinstalling?

Tags: server, raid, webserver, partitioning

I have a HP DL380 G7 Server with the HW Raid configured at Raid 1+0. Previously, I have 146GB LFF SAS Installed but I since have upgraded to 600GB LFF SAS Drives.

Since the Mirror Rebuilding was based on the 146GB Image, I have around 450GB of unused space which I want to integrate to the / filesystem.

I am using this box as a web server. It is running a PHP Web Application with its DB as MySQL. I want to maximize the space for MySQL to use since this Web Application is doing thousands of transactions per day.

How do I change the volume size of the / filesystem without reinstalling?

Are there any other suggestions to better maximize my system's resources?

If needed, here are my specs.

Operating system    Ubuntu Linux 12.04.3

Kernel and CPU Linux 3.8.0-31-generic on x86_64

Processor information   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5630 @ 2.53GHz, 16 cores

Real memory 418.78 MB used, 23.54 GB total

Box HP ProLiant DL380 G7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using an HP Server and an HP RAID Controller, I just reconfigured the current RAID Setup to reflect the HDD Size. After that, I used the HPACUCLI package to expand the partition.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to configure the hardware raid to increase the size of the virtual disk.  If you have already done that, then you need to expand the partition, then tell the filesystem to use the new space.

Expanding the partition can be done using `parted`.  Use the `unit s` command to have it use sectors as the units and `print` the existing table.  Then delete the existing partition with the `rm` command, and recreate it with the `mkpart` command.  Be sure to use the exact same starting sector, and make the length longer.  You may need to reboot for this to take effect.

Then use the `resize2fs` command ( assuming you are using the ext4 filesystem ) to expand the filesystem into the new space.

Comment: Hi @psusi. Thank you for this. I will try it over during the weekends as this is a production server, I have to restart to modify the RAID settings. I will post what happens here...